# Multiplying an Unbiased estimator by a constant

Tags: statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

In my textbook, Introduction to Probability and Statistical Applications, s^2 is an unbiased estimator for the variance. However, when this estimator is multiplied by some constant a, the estimator is now biased with a bias of (1-a) multiplied by the variance. Could someone please explain why?

Thank you very much

Comment: Which textbook are you using? What are you studying?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbiased means by definition that the expectation is the variance:
$$\mathbb{E}[s^2] = \sigma^2$$
When you multiply by some $a$, the expectation is now, by linearity of expectation,
$$\mathbb{E}[as^2] = a\sigma^2$$
so the bias (which is, again by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator), how the expectation of your estimator differs from the quantity you seek to estimate):
$$\textrm{bias} =\mathbb{E}[as^2]-\sigma^2 = (a-1)\sigma^2$$